# Webpack 4: Copying pictures and fonts

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I create a project with the following structure:

[image: Screenshot with project structure]

Webpack 4 configuration:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
path: __dirname + '/web'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: { minimize: true }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: __dirname + '/fonts'
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
    use: {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        name(file) {
          if (env === 'development') {
            return './images/[name].[ext]'
          }

          return '[hash].[ext]'
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: './index.html'
}),
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css',
  chunkFilename: '[id].css'
})
  ]
};
```

After compilation, `the main.js`, `main.css` and `index.html` are placed in the web folder. How to make all the pictures in the project copied to the web/images, and the fonts in the web/fonts?

In the project, I refer to them as follows:

1) src\Interface\Header\Index.js

```
<img src="img/logo.png" srcSet="img/logo@2x.png 2x, img/logo@3x.png 3x" className="header-logo" alt=""/>
```

2) src\Pages\App\style.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeueCyr';
src: url('/fonts/HelveticaNeueCyr.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/HelveticaNeueCyr.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
path: __dirname + '/web'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: { minimize: true }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'fonts'
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
    use: {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'images'
      }
    }
  }
]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: './index.html'
}),
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css',
  chunkFilename: '[id].css'
})
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks, with the fonts turned out (
could be done as follows:  `options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts'
          }`
)       Pictures are still not copied

Comment: No. Pictures are not copied. Maybe the file-loader analyzes only the CSS?

Comment: No, those rules are not applied to css. It works here for me... i have no idea why it is not.

Comment: Ok. Do you know why it does not work? Because you are importing images like this: `src="img/logo.png"`. By doing that, webpack wont know about it. You need to `import image from "img/logo.png"` then `<img src={image}...`

Comment: Thanks, now everything is copied)

Comment: Hi @PlayMa256 ! Can you please review my post? (has a git repo in my last comment): https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/299